# For a C# List, how do I reorder a column when one record's value changes?

Tags: c#, list, recursion, collections, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid where the user can change the order of the rows by moving the rows up and down.  I adjust the order field by incrementing or decrementting it by one.  I now need to reorder the rest of the items in the grid.  The pass the data back to a controller and am now trying to reorder the list.  I feel like I'm close, but can't quite get it right.  Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Example:

Start with this grid

```
Test | Order
  A  | 1
  B  | 2
  C  | 3
  D  | 4
```

The user clicks on the B row and the up arrow so the grid now looks like this:

```
Test | Order
  B  | 1
  A  | 1
  C  | 3
  D  | 4
```

This part is all working fine so I don't think any code is necessary.  Here's where I need help.  So I get to the controller and I have a list like this:

```
[0] Test: B, Order: 1
[1] Test: A, Order: 1
[2] Test: C, Order: 3
[3] Test: D, Order: 4
```

There are two records where the order equals 1.  How do I reorder the list (so that I can save the new order to the database?

What I want is a list that looks like this:

```
[0] Test: B, Order: 1
[1] Test: A, Order: 2
[2] Test: C, Order: 3
[3] Test: D, Order: 4
```

I came up with this solution, but the recursive part isn't working right.  The list I get returned is blank.  Can someone find what's wrong?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateComments([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ModelComment model)
    {
        List<ModelComment> comments = new List<ModelComment>();

        comments.Add(model);

        List<ModelComment> otherComments = data.GetCommentsByAnalysisID(model.analysisID);

        List<ModelComment> changedComments = ChangeDuplicateOrders(otherComments, model.commentsSelectedID, model.order);

        return Json(comments.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    private List<ModelComment> ChangeDuplicateOrders(List<ModelComment> comments, int ID, int order)
    {
        List<ModelComment> changedComments = new List<ModelComment>();

        foreach (ModelComment comment in comments)
        {
            if (comment.commentsSelectedID != ID)
            {
                ModelComment changedComment = comment;

                if (comment.order == order)
                {
                    changedComment.order = order + 1;
                    changedComments.Add(changedComment);
                }

                List<ModelComment> remainingComments = new List<ModelComment>();
                remainingComments = comments;
                remainingComments.Remove(changedComment);

                List<ModelComment> processedcomments = ChangeDuplicateOrders(remainingComments, changedComment.commentsSelectedID, changedComment.order);
                changedComments = (changedComments.Concat(processedcomments)).ToList();
            }
        }

        return changedComments;
    }
```

Edit:
Here's the view so that you can see what I'm doing on the client side:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LabApprovals_History", "Home"))
{
<div class="breadcrumb">
    @Html.Raw(@ClsUtility.GetCurrentCrumb("Lab Approvals Comments"))
</div>
if (@ViewBag.Message != null && @ViewBag.Message != "")
{
    <div id="divErrorMessage" style="color: #1A78C2;">
        <br />
        @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Message)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="clear: both">
        <br />
    </div>
}
<br />
<div style="text-align: center; padding-left: 10px;">
    <div id="grid"></div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DALubeBarcode.Models.ModelComment>().Name("gridComments")
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Read(read => read.Action("ReadComments", "Home", new { analysisID = Model.analysisID }))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateComments", "Home"))
                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.commentsSelectedID))
                            )
                            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Save())
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(m => m.commentsSelectedID).Visible(false);
                                columns.Bound(m => m.commentText).Title("Comment").Width("500px");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.order)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input type='button' class='k-button' onclick=up(\'#=uid#\') value='up' />").Title("");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.order)
                                    .ClientTemplate("<input type='button' class='k-button' onclick=down(\'#=uid#\') value='down' />").Title("");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.order).Title("Order").Width("50px");
                            })
                        .Sortable()
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })
                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
)
</div>

}

<script>
function up(uid) {
    var grid = $("#gridComments").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    dataItem.order = dataItem.order - 1;

    var index = grid.dataSource.indexOf(dataItem);
    var newIndex = Math.max(0, index - 1);

    if (newIndex != index) {
        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
    }

    var dataSource = $("#gridComments").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    dataSource.data()[newIndex].dirty = true;
    dataSource.sync();

    return false;
}

function down(uid) {
    var grid = $("#gridComments").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    dataItem.order = dataItem.order + 1;

    var index = grid.dataSource.indexOf(dataItem);
    var newIndex = Math.min(grid.dataSource.total() - 1, index + 1);

    if (newIndex != index) {
        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
    }

    var dataSource = $("#gridComments").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    dataSource.data()[newIndex].dirty = true;
    dataSource.sync();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the client to do this work? JavaScript should take care of this. Your server side code shouldn't be worried about anything but saving the data once it gets there. Also, you can modify the object you're working with to make your job a lot less complicated on the server if you must. For example: `List<Dictionary<int, ModelComment>> test;` where `int` holds your order.

Comment: @MarkC. Thanks for the reply.  The reason I was doing this on the server side is that I couldn't figure out how to get the values of the other rows in the Kendo grid from jQuery.  I can get the selected row's value, but I don't know how to reference the rest of the rows.  If you have some suggestions on how to do this on the client side, I'd love to hear them.  I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days and really need to get a solution soon before my bosses start complaining about how much time I've spent on this.  Thanks again!

Comment: I know I'm gonna be asking a lot here, but if you could put together a JSFiddle with purely Kendo + your jQuery I think it would help solve your problem immensely. (From the client side)

Comment: Am I missing something?  If you just need to reorder the list, why use recursion?  See my solution and see if I am just not understanding you right.

Comment: Not sure that recursion is necessary.  Was thinking I needed it because I needed to compare every item to every other item.  In my example it's pretty simple since I just need to change one item, but in a larger sample, several items may have their order changed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, but I dont have the time to check the syntax, so watch out for capitalization and such:

```
 private void reorder (myList, oldIndex, newIndex) {
     ModelComment itemToMove = myList.First(x=>x.order==oldIndex);
     ModelComment insertPoint = myList.First(x=>x.order==newIndex);
     myList.Remove(itemToMove);
     if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
         myList.select(x=>x.order>=newIndex && x.order<oldIndex).foreach(x=>x.order++);
     } else {
         myList.select(x=>x.order<=newIndex && x.order>oldIndex).foreach(x=>x.order--);
     }
     itemToMove.order = newIndex;
     myList.Insert(myList.IndexOf(insertPoint), itemToMove);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't understand what "oldIndex" and "newIndex" are.  Can you explain?

Comment: ok, i had actually forgotten to move the item itslef, so I made those changes.  and old index is the old order number of the item, and new index is the new order number.  So if you want to move item b from row 2 to row 1, you would call reorder(mylist, 2, 1).  Incidentally, this could handle something like moving item C from row 3 to row 9 (multiple rows and either up or down).

Comment: This assumes that your "order" stays in straight, 1 indexed sequence.  I will modify it in a second so that won't matter.

Comment: ok, now it does not care whether "order" is in a straight sequence starting at 1 and incremented by 1.